# JavaScript/CSS - Update value *and* size of multiple input elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic, input

I have a numerical base conversion page with html, javascript and css (no external jquery) where I type into one input field and then in real time it updates multiple other input fields with a corresponding value in a different base for each input field. These multiple values, about 5 dozen of them, are all different lengths, so I manually set up each of their input lengths with size="43", size="50", etc. Is it possible to also in real time update the size of each input field to match its dynamically-updated content, with javascript and css but not jquery? Each one is also in its own div if that helps, or it could be in its own span if needed.
I have tried at least half a dozen suggestions I found online but none have worked so far, because they all depend on either 1) "onkey" or "blur" events, of which there are none except on my 1 input field where I type, so that does not work for any of the other dozens of fields, or 2) updating one specific input field by specific name, and that doesn't apply either because I have dozens, each with a different input id.
A short and elegant solution would be preferable but I'm willing to try anything. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it myself with :

```
document.getElementById("foo").style.width = ((document.getElementById("foo").value.length + 1) * 6.5);
```

it's pretty close, not 100%, as far as the style width matching the input element contents, but at least it's dynamic which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setAttribute` command to change the value of elements.Refer to the sample below.

**HTML**

```
<td><input type=text name=script_id id="id" onblur="myFunctionY(this)" placeholder="19506"></td>
<td><input type=text name=dep id="dep" placeholder="dependency"></td>
```

**JS**

```
<script type=text/javascript>
function myFunctionY(vari) {
console.log(vari.value);
document.query_form.dep.setAttribute("value",vari.value);
   }
</script>
```

*dep is the id for an input element
query_form is the form name*

Essentially, call a function `onblur`,which then gets the input value entered.Use the setAttribute function for the form name to update a particular value of an input field.

Comment: is there a live demo, jsfiddle, or something similar? I tried it on my page with an existing input, also tried it on a blank template page, and both ways there is just a "19506" static input, and a "dependency" static input. <br> looking for something like: 1) type into input#1. 2) input#2 and input#3 values are updated real-time (already have this part). 3) input#2 and input#3 sizes are also updated real-time to fit the updated values (would like to have this. don't have it yet.)

Comment: Hi, just created this, check it out. [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyqwGz)  .You can set pretty much any attribute that way.

Comment: this following link is very close to what I'm looking for, if the second field size and value would update along with the first field, when data is entered into the first field: (http://jsfiddle.net/4Qsa8/)

Comment: Isn't the link I sent you doing exactly that?Second field size (and now the value), is updating according to previous inputs.

Comment: it doesn't work for me, in Firefox 40-something (win7 x64), Pale Moon 25-ish (win7 x64), nor the stock Android 4.1.2 browser. in all those browsers, box 2 resizes to the size of box 1 as soon as I tab away from box 1, and then nothing ever changes after that. values of neither box ever change unless I change them manually. Opera Mobile 12 crashes but I think it's the fault of codepen.io